# How do I use an array of Movieclip names to control those clips in as3?

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, actionscript

I have an old little program I am trying to rebuild for Adobe animate (originally it was in Flash - actionscript 1)
Here is the bit of code I am trying to make work (worked fine back in the day in as1)

```
function getoddnumbers(){
for(i=1;i<=100;i+=2){with(eval("answer"+i))gotoAndStop(3);

}
}
```

So I know the eval doesnt work anymore so I took it out-

```
    var i:Number;
    function getoddnumbers(){
    for(i=1;i<=100;i+=2){with("answer"+i)gotoAndStop(3);

    }
    }
```

But now as3 doesnt like the gotoAndStop() command.  Any ideas how I can use the array of names answer1, answer2 etc to control those movieclips?
thanks for your help
Have a great day

Answer (score 0):

With AS3 a MovieClip's playhead can be controlled using the **gotoAndStop** function just like with AS2. Your code above most likely doesn't work because `with("answer"+i)` doen't return a MovieClip instance so it won't be able to find it's gotoAndStop method.

Given that you put all of your MovieClip instances on stage via Flash's IDE and all have an **instance** name set via it's properties panel you can get a reference to those by it's name using the **getChildByName()** function.
Try replacing

```
for(i=1;i<=100;i+=2){with("answer"+i)gotoAndStop(3);}
```

by

```
for(i=1;i<=100;i+=2)
{
    MovieClip(getChildByName("answer"+i)).gotoAndStop(3);
}
```